# Disable GPS Location alerts when searching with ChromeDriver on Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script that searches Bing using chromedriver and selenium. When using mobile emulation, some searches trigger a GPS location alert notification. My question is, how can I disable these alerts completely on Chrome?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
UA_MOBILE = { "deviceName": "Apple iPhone 6 Plus" }

chromeOptionsMobile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptionsMobile.add_experimental_option('mobileEmulation', UA_MOBILE)

prefs = {
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications' : 2,
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation' : 2,
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.popups' : 2,
    }

chromeOptionsMobile.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```

Alert Image: [GPS Location Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRRjj.png)

Any ideas?